# How to generate key with RSA and aes-256-gcm?

Tags: openssl

I want to generate key with RSA and AES 256 GCM but I am getting following error every time:

```
$ openssl genpkey -out mkey.pem -aes-256-gcm -algorithm rsa
.........................++++++
..............++++++
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Error writing key
140735190483024:error:0D0A7072:asn1 encoding routines:PKCS5_pbe2_set_iv:error setting cipher params:p5_pbev2.c:133:
140735190483024:error:2307D00D:PKCS12 routines:PKCS8_encrypt:ASN1 lib:p12_p8e.c:86:
```

OpenSSL version `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`.
Max OS X 10.11.

---

When I try to use `aes-256-ctr` I also get error but slightly different:

```
openssl genpkey -out mkey.pem -aes-256-ctr -algorithm rsa
.................++++++
.....++++++
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Error writing key
140735190483024:error:0D0A706C:asn1 encoding routines:PKCS5_pbe2_set_iv:cipher has no object identifier:p5_pbev2.c:104:
140735190483024:error:2307D00D:PKCS12 routines:PKCS8_encrypt:ASN1 lib:p12_p8e.c:86:
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).